# C# OData URI Parser Without Metadata?

Tags: c#, nuget, odata

Does anybody know of a nuget package or any other decent method of parsing an OData request that doesn't require $metadata? I'd love to be able to use something like Microsoft's [OData URI Parser](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/odata/odatalib/use-uri-parser) but it relies on a $metadata URL and appears to collapse without it. The service I'm working with can't have one (internal business decision) but I still need a good way of getting the $filter and $orderby data out of a request.

Ideally, I'm looking for something which I can pass the full query string to and then it will give me a filter object with a collection of filter clauses in it which I can then handle in my own way.

I've scoured MS and nuget.org with little success.

Comment: metadata is the response from a request.  So what is being returned from the request to the service?  Usually you get data and the Controller processes the data into c# classes.

Comment: The data returned by the service varies greatly depending on a few things. It's not built as a particular C# class and converted, the JSON is built dynamically instead. This is because each of our clients uses different fields and names their fields differently, so there's no "consistent object" that we can map the results to. This is why I can't have a $metadata URL with all the proper XML describing the object and therefore can't use the Microsoft ODataURIParser.

Comment: You metadata is the jason and you want a custom parser.  See :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/odata/webapi/custom-query-options-parser

Comment: My understanding is $metadata and my json response are very different things. E.g. here's an example $metadata http://services.odata.org/V4/TripPinService/$metadata which is a full description of what the types returned by any queries are, not just an example of a response. I'm not sure that using a custom parser helps me here as the URI Parser still needs a $metadata URL for it to understand how to serialize the requests.

Comment: Your link is an xml edmx mapping file.  OData is a general purpose data intereface with lots of inherited classes.  The EDMX is one type and there are many JSON libraries that also inherit the OData class.

Comment: The JSON returned by my service does nothing to explain the types though. I just need something that can take something like $filter=FirstName eq 'Scott' and turn it into a collection of objects which I can then use to generate SQL. The OData URI Parser would do this, but only with metadata. I need a method without metadata.

Comment: There are projects in GITHUB that take JSON and automatically create the c# classes.

Comment: That doesn't help me though because my objects will vary depending on who is requesting them. For some clients they will have three fields, for others they will have 30 fields. The names of the fields will vary and can be changed in the DB. I can't use a c# file as my model.

Comment: For the ODATA to work, you need the correct interfaces,  You can use the standard interfaces or you can develop your own custom interfaces inheriting the ODATA classes.  There is no way around having the required interfaces that is compatible with your data. The interface can be dynamic, but you must have the interfaces.

Comment: I’m implementing something similar to this but in my case, I can reconstruct the model from information available in the database. How are you determining what is a valid entity set / attribute / etc if you don’t have a model? Are they passing column / table names verbatim?